# Change language for text-to-speech Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis

Tags: text-to-speech, microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

I found how to change gender, rate, and volume, but I'm wondering if it possible to change -or better if I can get ability to set- several different languages to choose for `Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis` text to speech. I just can't find useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   You'll need to [install the voices](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224), but the Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis runtime engine has a *lot* of different languages available.   (At the link, you can see a bunch of files starting with `MSSpeech_TTS` - these are the TTS voices.

Then you can use [SpeechSynthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd130174(v=office.14).aspx) to specify a language using CultureInfo.